# merging dicts in python

Tags: python, arrays, merge

I am new to python..I have two sorted arrays (by key) that I would like to merge. Both arrays have some common keys and some exist uniquely in one of the arrays. I want to do an outer join.

```
Array1 = {'key_1': 10, 'key_2': 14,..'key_m': 321}
Array2 = {'key_1': 15, 'key_2': 12..'key_m':2,..'key_n':34}
```

I want to merge using key_1..key_n..

```
Array3 = [[key_1',10,15],['key_2':14:12],..]
```

I don't have numpy package installed on my computer. Do I need it to merge this array? what is the best way to code this up? Thanks!!!

Comment: They look like dictionary to me!

Comment: First, those are dictionaries, not arrays. Second, dictionaries can not be structured the way you want them in Array3. They must be in key:value _pairs_ only.

Comment: Python's "Array" is either a dictionary (like a hash table) or a list (like a sequence). See http://www.wellho.net/solutions/python-python-list-python-tuple-python-dictionary.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import chain

dict1 = {'key_1': 10, 'key_2': 14, 'key_m': 321}
dict2 = {'key_1': 15, 'key_2': 12, 'key_m':2, 'key_n':34}

dict3 = {}

# Go through all keys in both dictionaries
for key in set(chain(dict1, dict2)):

    # Find the key in either dictionary, using an empty
    # string as the default if it is not found.
    dict3[key] = [dict.get(key, "")
                  for dict in (dict1, dict2)]

print(dict3)
```

Now `dict3` has a list of every value from the input arrays.

Or if you want it in that `[[key, value, value], [key, value, value]...]` format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import chain

dict1 = {'key_1': 10, 'key_2': 14, 'key_m': 321}
dict2 = {'key_1': 15, 'key_2': 12, 'key_m':2, 'key_n':34}

result = [[key] + [dict.get(key, "")
           for dict in (dict1, dict2)]
          for key in set(chain(dict1, dict2))]
result.sort()

print(result)
```

Comment: What if there are actually values of `None` in the dictionary? You're also missing a parenthesis after the 2nd `get`, and you can use just `chain(array1, array2)` if you don't mind being a bit less explicit.

Comment: In his comment to the other answer he said he wants an empty value if it's not in the dict, so you probably want `append(dict.get(key, ''))`.

Comment: @Brendan Long - how do I make the arrays last element look like ['key_n','',34]? thanks..

Comment: @papu - Here you go (the second code snippet). I think it would be more Pythonic to use `None` to represent values that don't exist, rather than the empty string though.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Array3` has incorrect syntax.   You can try something like this:

```
>>> Array1 = {'key_1': 10, 'key_2': 14, 'key_m': 321}
>>> Array2 = {'key_1': 15, 'key_2': 12, 'key_m':2, 'key_n':34}
>>>
>>> Array3_dict = dict()
>>> for Array in (Array1, Array2):
...     for key, value in Array.items():
...         if not key in Array3_dict: Array3_dict[key] = list()
...         Array3_dict[key].append(value)
...
>>> Array3 = [ [ key ] + value for key, value in Array3_dict.items() ]
>>> Array3.sort()
>>> print Array3
[['key_1', 10, 15], ['key_2', 14, 12], ['key_m', 321, 2], ['key_n', 34]]
>>>
```

Comment: thanks. The last element should look like ['key_n','',34]..is is a n by 3 array

Comment: Use `Array3_dict = defaultdict(list)` so you don't need the `if not key` part.